# Binding a SqlDataSource to a GridView: What is the difference between binding via ID and via setting DataSource

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, sqldatasource

I want to bind a SqlDataSource to a GridView for viewing and editing database records.

No big deal (I thought).

However, there seems to be a big conceptual difference between

- **binding via the 'DataSourceID' property** of the GridView declaratively in the aspx file
- **binding by setting the 'DataSource' propert**y in code behind

With the first, I could immediately get editing capabilities by declaring an additional Edit button, with the second, I was not able to get the updated values into the database at all.

**What is the difference between those two, really?**

Note: I am not so much interested in getting code as an answer, but more of an explanation or manual about the differences.

Answer (score 1):

GridView1.DataSourceID requires the id of a Datasource object, typically a datasource control like SqlDataSource dropped on a page.

when using the page designer you can "wire up" the datasource to the gridview using the gridview context menu.

Or it can be set programmatically, say in Page_Load:

```
    GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID
```

Gridview supports a number of data source controls, you are not limited to SqlDataSource.

The main difference has to do with binding and the page lifecycle.

When you specify `GridView1.DataSourceID` and assuming the control is visible, Data binding will occur auto-magically during the Databind events of the page lifecycle.

If you specify `GridView1.DataSource` databinding becomes a programmer's obligation.  Binding will not happen until you explicitly make a call to `GridView1.DataBind()`

#### One more thing

If using a SqlDataSource there is a nifty little property called `CancelSelectOnNullParameter`.  This should be is self-explanatory, and it defaults to TRUE. Just something to be aware of as it's caused me much frustration in my early days.

Comment: Can you provide some links or more details about the "auto-magical" binding with the DataSourceID. Would this be more than just setting the DataSource and calling DataBind?

Comment: Sure: here is [the Page LifeCycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) and further down the same page, [the DataBinding events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx#data_binding_events_for_databound_controls)

Comment: Also - in its most basic, simplistic implementation, you can either set the `DataSourceID` property and let the page handle the binding operations, or you can set the `DataSource` and handling the binding programmatically.  You will find that occasionally, even using the former, you may be required to make calls to `DataBind()` as Caching and ViewState play a role in determining what you see in the gridview.